# Collision Detection Excel Formula

Tags: excel

I have a machine that inserts components into a circuit board.  It has a certain area that if the already placed parts are too close to the one being inserted then the already placed part will be smashed.  I order this list of insertions to avoid such collisions, but I have no way of testing a long list against previous insertions without filling a spreadsheet with the formula have come up with.  Here is the information;

```
`=IF(AND(AND(OR(AND(Xe-115 <= Xh + 230, Xe-115 >= Xh - 130),AND(Xh+115 <= Xe + 230, Xh+115 >= Xe - 130)), OR(AND(Ye-115 <= Yh+36, Ye-115 >= Yh-403),AND(Ye+115 <= Yh+36, Ye+115 >= Yh-403)))), "Collision", "GOOD")`
```

I'd take that and compare it to every insertion by making a table.  But a big board would crash my computer.  I'd rather have an argument that compared this cell to every cell above it and have it tell me when it finds a collision.

Logic:
    `If [(Xh-130) <= (Xe + or - Xr) <= (Xh+230)] AND [(Yh-(comp height + 19)) <= (Ye + or - Yr) <= (Yh+36)] Then Collision`

```
(Xh, Yh) = Coordinates of the Part that is being Inserted.
(Xe, Ye) = Coordinates of Already-Inserted Part.
115 = Assumed Radius of the Already-Inserted Part.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many parts are you talking about? Also, can your collision detection be simplified to taking the distance between part X and part Y and just checking that the distance > 2x assumed radius?

Answer (score 0):

Since a Comment does not suit an image:

[image]

The co-ordinates shown for components #3 and #4 are not viable because the distance between their centres is less than the sum of their radii.